# Necesito realizar un slider responsivo con thumbnail pero que se respete la proporción de las dimensiones de la imagenes

Tags: jquery, html5, css, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

He estado buscando un slider carousel con thumbnail responsivo, sin que las imagenes se deformen por los diferentes tamaños que pueda tener. He visto varios slider responsivos de bootstrap, pero al colocar imagenes de anchos y largo distinto, se ven mal. Una forma de evitar esas deformaciones es mantener un ancho y alto fijo, y mostrar un fondo negro en los extremos sobrante, como el ejemplo de la foto[image: ejemplo de un slider donde se ve los bordes negros en los extremos horizontal]

Me gustaría saber donde podría encontrar un slider similar a este (además, que se agrande la imagen)pero responsivo:
http://www.emol.com/noticias/Espectaculos/2016/02/29/790587/Mejores-y-peores-vestidas-Oscar-2016.html#1509383/Los-"mejores"-y-"peores"-vestidos-de-los-Oscar-2016
No se si me explique bien, pero desde ya, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Componente seguro hay muchos

[30 Free Responsive Jquery Carousel Slider Plugins](http://designscrazed.org/free-responsive-jquery-carousel-slider-plugins/)

pero podria sugerir

[pgwslideshow](http://pgwjs.com/pgwslideshow/)

en el mismo link tiene una demo del slide para ver como se visualizan las imagenes